# IronPython 3.4.1 in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, ironpython

I'm creating a game on Unity 2023.2.2f1 where the player writes code and I need to execute the code as a Python file. Is it possible to do that with IronPython?

I connected it but I can't seem to get ir built, it throws out a fatal error:

```
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\WinPlayerBuildProgram\ManagedStripped failed with output:
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2023.2.2f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build\deploy\UnityLinker.exe @Library\Bee\artifacts\rsp\16160435148306878684.rsp
Fatal error in Unity CIL Linker
Mono.Linker.LinkerFatalErrorException: ILLink: error IL1005: IronPython.Runtime.PythonFile.<CreatePipe>g__InitializePipesUnix|24_0(<>c__DisplayClass24_0&): Error processing method 'IronPython.Runtime.PythonFile.<CreatePipe>g__InitializePipesUnix|24_0(<>c__DisplayClass24_0&)' in assembly 'IronPython.dll'
 ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Mono.Posix, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Common.MissingMethodStubber.GetTypeModule(TypeReference type, IEnumerable`1 assemblies)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.AddUnresolvedStubsStep.MarkAssemblyOfType(UnityLinkContext context, TypeReference type)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.Marking.UnresolvedStubMarking.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference, DependencyInfo reason, IMemberDefinition sourceLocationMember)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method, DependencyInfo& reason)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method, DependencyInfo& reason)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityPipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.UnityRun(UnityLinkContext context, UnityPipeline p, LinkRequest linkerOptions, TinyProfiler2 tinyProfiler, ILogger customLogger)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriverWithoutErrorHandling(TinyProfiler2 tinyProfiler, ILogger customLogger)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriverWithoutErrorHandling()
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriver()

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Comment: Did you check .net version of the IronPython.dll file? And also please read this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html

and also there is a python package: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.scripting.python@7.0/manual/index.html

but i'm not sure about runtime compatibility.